# Filter Data Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need help on creating a formula/code on data filtering.
I have 4 columns of data as below:

```
Column A     Column B      Column C     Column D
__________________________________________________
|  ID           TEST        FUNCTION      SCRATCH |
|_________________________________________________|
|92018211        Y            WELL                |
|72937191                                         |
|01221921                     WELL          Yes   |
|72901921        Y                          Yes   |
|00192839        Y            WELL          Yes   |
|_________________________________________________|
```

I want to filter my data into if any of the column B,C and D is blank, the data should be visible.

The data that have value in all three column B,C,D is the data that I do not want.

Example: Example the data that have value Y in column B, value WELL in column C, value Yes in Column D

So from my data above, after filter the data should be like below:

```
Column A     Column B      Column C     Column D
__________________________________________________
|  ID           TEST        FUNCTION      SCRATCH |
|_________________________________________________|
|92018211        Y            WELL                |
|72937191                                         |
|01221921                     WELL          Yes   |
|72901921        Y                          Yes   |
|                                                 |
|_________________________________________________|
```

I would like to do the formula/code using excel macro Autofiltering.

Any help from anyone is much appreciated. Really hope anyone able to help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a column E with the formula `=OR(ISBLANK(D2),ISBLANK(C2),ISBLANK(D2))`

This formula returns a `FALSE` when data is present all three columns (B, C, D)

After this you can apply a filter and delete the rows where column E is `FALSE`. This would you give you the desired result.